# iOS build failure upon using CN1Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, codenameone

I'm receiving  a build failure after including the CN1Bluetooth code into my app. It's in the lib folder and had been refreshed. Worked on Android, won't compile for iOS.

The following is from the error file:

Executing: echo chmod 0755 /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb chmod 0755 /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb
Executing: chmod 0755 /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb Executing: echo /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb
Executing: /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb `<PBXGroup name=`Frameworks`UUID=`0F634E7718E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA218E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `children`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
`<PBXGroup name=`Products`UUID=`0F634E7618E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA118E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `children`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
`<PBXNativeTarget name=`ShopMyLocalStoresTests`UUID=`0F634EA018E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA118E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `product_reference`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
`<PBXFrameworksBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9E18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA318E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
`<PBXFrameworksBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9E18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EA418E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
`<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`0F634E9F18E9ABBC002F3D1D`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0F634EAD18E9ABBC002F3D1D` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
Error during processing: undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
Backtrace:
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/buildable_reference.rb:89:in`construct_buildable_name'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/buildable_reference.rb:59:in `set_reference_target'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/buildable_reference.rb:16:in`block in initialize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/xml_element_wrapper.rb:53:in `create_xml_element_with_fallback'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/buildable_reference.rb:14:in`initialize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/build_action.rb:96:in `new'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/build_action.rb:96:in`block in initialize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/xml_element_wrapper.rb:53:in `create_xml_element_with_fallback'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/build_action.rb:77:in`initialize'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme.rb:186:in `new'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme.rb:186:in`add_build_target'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:756:in `block in recreate_user_schemes'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:754:in`each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:754:in `recreate_user_schemes'
    /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb:5:in`'
An error occurred recreating schemes, but the build still might work...

---

Write auxiliary files
/bin/mkdir -p /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build
write-file /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-generated-files.hmap
write-file /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-own-target-headers.hmap
write-file /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova.hmap
write-file /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-all-target-headers.hmap
/bin/mkdir -p /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7
write-file /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Cordova.LinkFileList
write-file /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
write-file /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-project-headers.hmap

CompileC /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVCommandDelegateImpl.o Cordova/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCommandDelegateImpl.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_RELEASE=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -iquote /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-generated-files.hmap -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-own-target-headers.hmap -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-project-headers.hmap -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Cordova/include -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Private -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Private/Cordova -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/Cordova -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/DerivedSources -F/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Cordova -DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0 -include /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Cordova/Cordova-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVCommandDelegateImpl.d --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVCommandDelegateImpl.dia -c /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Cordova/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCommandDelegateImpl.m -o /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVCommandDelegateImpl.o

CompileC /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVCommandQueue.o Cordova/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCommandQueue.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_RELEASE=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -iquote /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-generated-files.hmap -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-own-target-headers.hmap -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-project-headers.hmap -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Cordova/include -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Private -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Private/Cordova -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/Cordova -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/DerivedSources -F/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Cordova -DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0 -include /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Cordova/Cordova-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVCommandQueue.d --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVCommandQueue.dia -c /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Cordova/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCommandQueue.m -o /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVCommandQueue.o
/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Cordova/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCommandQueue.m:197:22: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 3
        objc_msgSend(obj, normalSelector, command);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

CompileC /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVConfigParser.o Cordova/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVConfigParser.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_RELEASE=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -iquote /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-generated-files.hmap -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-own-target-headers.hmap -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-project-headers.hmap -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Cordova/include -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Private -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Private/Cordova -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/Cordova -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/DerivedSources -F/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Cordova -DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0 -include /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Cordova/Cordova-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVConfigParser.d --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVConfigParser.dia -c /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Cordova/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVConfigParser.m -o /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVConfigParser.o

CompileC /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVInvokedUrlCommand.o Cordova/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVInvokedUrlCommand.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_RELEASE=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -iquote /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-generated-files.hmap -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-own-target-headers.hmap -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Cordova-project-headers.hmap -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Cordova/include -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Private -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Private/Cordova -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/Cordova -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/DerivedSources -F/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Cordova -DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0 -include /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Cordova/Cordova-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVInvokedUrlCommand.d --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVInvokedUrlCommand.dia -c /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/Pods/Cordova/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVInvokedUrlCommand.m -o /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVInvokedUrlCommand.o

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build6615573583221835807xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/Cordova.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVCommandQueue.o Cordova/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCommandQueue.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Comment: Is this an appstore build or a debug build?

Comment: A debug. I've been looking at three things. The iOS configuration, the iOS native code for a null class, and my iOS certificate/app ID/provisioning profile. I always appreciate your help, but I travel a lot and sometimes can't get back on a timely basis.

Comment: I've asked Steve to look at this build error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this was tested when we made our attempt to move to xcode 7 which we shortly thereafter reverted. So it seemed to work but it's currently failing because of the older version of xcode.

We will make the migration to the new xcode although it's hard to tell exactly when as we are rapidly approaching the code freeze. For now you can build with the `iphone_new` target as explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-server-migration-plan.html). This should become redundant once the migration goes thru but it's hard to tell when that will happen.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it ASAP. Right now I'm working on putting an Android version on a Raspberry Pi 3. I'd be happy to share my notes when I get done.

Comment: This is what I got: ** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
 CompileC build/Build/Intermediates/ShopMyLocalStores.build/Release-iphoneos/ShopMyLocalStores.build/Objects-normal/armv7/BluetoothLeCommandDelegateImpl.o ShopMyLocalStores-src/BluetoothLeCommandDelegateImpl.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Comment: This might be relevant because I had an issue with a corrupted private key earlier this year: Unable to delete certificate matching "iPhone Developer: Jeffery Crump (MBJPT5DX52)"Unable to delete certificate matching "iPhone Developer: Jeffery Crump (MBJPT5DX52)"Executing: security delete-keychain /Users/administrator/Library/Keychains/temp1468527359986.keychain security: SecKeychainDelete: The specified keychain could not be found.

Comment: I just spoke with Apple and the mismatched MBJPT5DX52 and Apple ID prefix is not a problem. However, I am not wholly convinced.

Comment: That's not the issue, I'll need the full error log.

Comment: Just post a link to the error log, notice it needs to be fresh enough as it expires within 3 days

Comment: Here it is https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/f2a612dc-03af-40f5-9b7e-ce33217bcc10-1468580265098-error.txt

Comment: This is the actual error `/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build3237332986303253710xxx/dist/ShopMyLocalStores-src/BluetoothLeCommandDelegateImpl.m:25:9: fatal error: 'com_codename1_cordova_CordovaCallbackManager.h' file not found
#import "com_codename1_cordova_CordovaCallbackManager.h"
        ^
1 error generated.` I'm sending it to Steve who worked on this

Comment: It looks like your cn1lib wasn't included properly in your project.  Try doing a "Clean" on your project, then select "Refresh CN1Libs".  Then send another build.  I just sent my bluetooth demo app to the "iphone_new" build server, and it built without any problem.

Comment: @stevehannah I recreated my Codename One project, copied the source files (none of which reference the Bluetooth libs), pasted the CN1Bluetooth.cn1lib and the CN1JSON.cn1lib from the compressed demo folder into the "libs" and refreshed the project from the Codename One menu. https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/d319ada0-7bac-4534-86d5-100c5931fabe-1468881286575-error.txt

Comment: /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build8634381750829808893xxx/dist/Pods/Cordova/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCommandQueue.m:197:22: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 3
        objc_msgSend(obj, normalSelector, command);

Comment: @stevehannah The build was built with target="iphone", I'm rebuilding with target="new_iphone". That was a consequence of recreating the project. Also on all of my previous builds I had recompiled your library the first time I loaded. This time they were taken from the zip file.

Comment: @stevehannah I just cancelled the new_iphone but, it has been queued for over two hours.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I built a base case without JSON & Bluetooth on "iphone_new" which compiled fine. I added JSON & Bluetooth from the JSON master and Bluetooth master, refreshed the libs and did a clean and build, then sent iPhone build. https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/55ad3193-d899-4ab1-8b28-f4b870c3720f-1468920220523-error.txt -  Have you tried creating a new project?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I created a from scratch copy of the demo. It is a "Hello World(bare bones)" app. I pasted the same CN1JSON and CN1Bluetoothle into the "lib" folder, executed "Refresh cn1 files". I replaced the main class source with the source from BTDemo. Running on android==> An internal application error occurred: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method. <init>(Ljava/util/HashMap;)V in class Lca/weblite/codename1/json/JSONObject; or its super classes (declaration of 'ca.weblite.codename1.json.JSONObject' appears in /data/app/com.crumptech.mobile.bluetoothtest-1/base.apk)

Comment: Did you actually use the API or just included the library? Is it possible you have the calls but don't invoke anything in a reachable way from start()/init()

Comment: Since it was taken from the BTDemo I pressed "enable bluetooth" which executes bt.enable() if !bt.enabled() and bt.requestPermissions() if !bt.hasPermissions(). That succeeded. Pressing "initialize" failed with the aforementioned error. After that "start scan" failed which was expected, and "stop scan" succeeded which was unexpected.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I think the problem in this case is that the CN1Bluetooth depends upon CN1JSON and that the dependency is not reflected by the "Refresh cn1lib files". Handling that dependency is still not very clear to me on how and where to place the zip file of the dependent compiled class files.

Comment: You don't place zip files. You just did a "Download" using the extension manager tool right? You just do that for the two files and it should work.

Comment: That must be my mistake. In the past I had downloaded cn1libs and manually placed them in the "lib" folder. What do I specifically need to do access the new classes from an existing cn1lib? Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog using the download manager in the plugin did solve the problem. I apologize for beating this to death, I sincerely appreciate  your help. I have been on site for 4 weeks working on this. All I need now is to be able to utilize the Bluetooth classes from within one of my cn1libs.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I need the "peripheral" command set as well as the "central". How can I add them to the downloaded CN1Bluetooth library. They are very simple and only to be needed to the existing Bluetooth.java. I was planning on adding them to a modified CN1Bluetooth for my project, but I now I have no idea on how to do that if must be installed by the download manager.

Comment: I found the original issue.  The version of the CN1Bluetooth library that was in the CodenameOneLibs project was out of date - did not include some necessary build hints.  I have updated the project so it should work correctly now from a fresh project.